# Easy way to find distribution of transformation?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose you have $X$ is $\operatorname{Normal}(\mu,\sigma^{2})$ and you want to find the pdf and cdf  of Y= $X^{a}$. What's an easy way to do this?

Comment: Are you making any assumptions on $a$? In particular $X^a$may be a complex number when $X$ is negative if $a$ is just a real number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We solve the problem for $a$ a positive integer. Let $f(x)$ be the density function of our normal, and $F(x)$ its cumulative distribution function. Note that $F(x)$ is not an elementary function.

Let $Y=X^a$. If $a$ is odd, then $Y\le y$ if and only if $X\le y^{1/a}$. This is $F(y^{1/a})$.  Thus the cumulative distribution function of $Y$ is $F(y^{1/a})$.

For the density function, differentiate. We get $\frac{1}{a}y^{\frac{1}{a}-1}f(y^{1/a})$. We have an explicit formula for $f(x)$, so by substituting we can find an explicit formula for the density of $Y$.

If $a$ is even, the situation is more complicated. Like before, let $Y=x^a$. If $y\lt 0$, then $\Pr(Y\le y)=0$. For $y\ge 0$, we have $Y\le y$ if $-y^{1/a}\le X\le y^{1/a}$.  Thus the cumulative distribution function of $Y$, for $y\ge 0$, is equal to $F(y^{1/a})-F(-y^{1/a})$.

For the density function, differentiate. We get $\frac{1}{a}y^{\frac{1}{a}-1}f(y^{1/a})+\frac{1}{a}y^{\frac{1}{a}-1}f(-y^{1/a})$.

**Remark:** For negative integers $a$, not much modification is needed. For negative odd integers, the direction of the inequality is reversed, but adjustment is relatively easy. What we get directly is $1$ minus the cdf.

One can extend the ideas to rational $a$ of the form $p/q$ where $p$ is odd.

Comment: $p/q$ should be a reduced fraction (that is, $\gcd(p,q) = 1$), right?

Comment: @DilipSarwate: One should probably specify reduced, though actually it doesn't matter since we have taken $q$ odd.

Comment: I should have thought before I typed. But, here is another query. Doesn't $p$ need to be odd, instead of $q$? I am thinking that if $p/q = 2/3$, say, which satisfies your requirements, then $$P\{Y \leq -1\} = P\{X^{2/3}\leq -1\} = P\{X \leq (-1)^{3/2}\} = P\{X \leq -i\}$$ where $i =\sqrt{-1}$ whereas with $p/q=3/2$, we have $$P\{Y \leq -1\} = P\{X^{3/2}\leq -1\} = P\{X \leq (-1)^{2/3}\} =  P\{X \leq -1\}$$

Comment: @DilipSarwate: If you are in a kindly mood, you can call it a typo. Yes, it is $p$ that is odd. Corrected.

Comment: Arrrgh, that last $X\leq -1$ should have read $X \leq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $a$ is an odd positive integer you can say
$$
F_{X^a}(t)=P[X^a \leq t] = P[X \leq t^{1/a}] = F_X(t^{1/a})
$$
Then differentiating
$$
f_{X^a}(t) = f_X(t^{1/a})\cdot \frac{1}{a}t^{1/a-1}.
$$

If $a$ is an even positive integer you can say for $t>0$
$$
F_{X^a}(t)=P[X^a \leq t] = P[|X| \leq t^{1/a}] =P[-t^{1/a} \leq X \leq t^{1/a}] = F_X(t^{1/a})-F_X(-t^{1/a})
$$
and $F_{X^a}(t)=0$ for all $t \leq 0$.

Differentiating then gives
$$
f_{X^a}(t) = 1_{t\geq 0}\cdot (f_X(t^{1/a})+f_X(-t^{1/a}))\frac{1}{a}t^{1/a-1}
$$
$$
= 1_{t\geq 0}\cdot f_X(t^{1/a})\frac{2}{a}t^{1/a-1}.
$$

You can plug in and simplify more using the specific form of $F_X$ and $f_X$ if you like.